# Errors creating a generic dbcontext class.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext, generic-list

I am trying to build a static dbcontext class to be used through out my core dll,

class definition...

```
public static class dbContext
{
    public static T Execute(Func<otherLib.dbContext, T> f)
    {
        using (var db = new otherLib.dbContext())
            return f(db);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Execute(Func<otherLib.dbContext, T> func)
    {
        using (var db = new otherLib.dbContext())
            return f(db);
    }
}
```

I want to use this generically sometimes returning a single typed item and other times returning a list hence the overload...

usage currently

```
    protected List<otherLib.foo1s> foo1;
    protected List<otherLib.foo2s> foo2;
    protected List<otherLib.foo3s> foo3;
            foo1 = dbContext.Execute(db => db.foo1s);
            foo2 = dbContext.Execute(db => db.foo2s);
            foo3 = dbContext.Execute(db => db.foo3s);
```

currently I get the standard error T repeated several times of course...

```
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone see where I went wrong with this...

Comment: Why are you doing this, as opposed to inheriting from Entity Framework's `DbContext` class and using that? It's not clear what your `Execute` functions are supposed to do, they look like they're returning something, even though "Execute" implies they perform something.

Comment: you aren't declaring type parameter `T` on your class or methods, to answer your question.  I would not recommend this approach though.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is pretty flawed.  For the compiler, you'll need to add a type parameter somewhere :

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<otherLib.dbContext, T> f)
{
    using (var db = new otherLib.dbContext())
        return f(db);
}
```

And even then, your method signatures are the same, and you'll get an error.

I have no idea how you'd use this approach efficiently, I'd do some research on generic repositories if that's what you're after.